# Simple table that converts units in real time using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

for my JavaScript homework, I wanted to create a simple table that converts length units. I tried using function "onchange" but nothing seems to happen. The idea is that when the user edits the "Meters" element, the script will change all other editable elements using "changem" function. Any tips will be helpful guys. Thank you

```
<table>

    <tr>

        <td>Meters</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" id="m" onchange="changem()">Enter value</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>Centimeters</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" id="cm">Enter value</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>Feet</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" id="feet">Enter value</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>Yards</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" id="yards">Enter value</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>Bananas</td>
        <td contenteditable = "true" id="bananas">Enter value</td>

    </tr>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function changem() {

        var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('m').innerHTML);

        document.getElementById('cm').innerHTML = x * 100;
        document.getElementById('feet').innerHTML = x * 3.28;
        document.getElementById('yards').innerHTML = x * 1.09;
        document.getElementById('bananas').innerHTML = x * 4.5;


    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching it to the `onkeyup` event instead

```
<td contenteditable="true" id="m" onkeyup="changem()">Enter value</td>
```

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) (onchange):

> Execute a JavaScript when a user changes the selected option of a `<select>` element

That's why your code wasn't working - there is no select element.

Comment: sorry, i meant to convey that there was no select element, thats why it wasnt working - edited

Answer (score 0):

`contenteditable` elements don't support the `onchange()` event, but they do support the `oninput()` event in some browsers:

```
<td contenteditable="true" id="m" oninput="changem()">Enter value</td>
```

**Example:**

```js
function changem() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('m').innerHTML);

  document.getElementById('cm').innerHTML = x * 100;
  document.getElementById('feet').innerHTML = x * 3.28;
  document.getElementById('yards').innerHTML = x * 1.09;
  document.getElementById('bananas').innerHTML = x * 4.5;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>

    <td>Meters</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" id="m" oninput="changem()">Enter value</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Centimeters</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" id="cm">Enter value</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Feet</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" id="feet">Enter value</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Yards</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" id="yards">Enter value</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Bananas</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" id="bananas">Enter value</td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Ideally, though, you should do this with `input` elements instead.

**Example:**

```js
function changem() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('m').value);

  document.getElementById('cm').innerHTML = x * 100;
  document.getElementById('feet').innerHTML = x * 3.28;
  document.getElementById('yards').innerHTML = x * 1.09;
  document.getElementById('bananas').innerHTML = x * 4.5;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>

    <td>Meters</td>
    <td><input id="m" oninput="changem()" placeholder="Enter value"></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Centimeters</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" id="cm">Enter value</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Feet</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" id="feet">Enter value</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Yards</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" id="yards">Enter value</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Bananas</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" id="bananas">Enter value</td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Onchage event only works with form elements.

Change your code eg:

```
<td>
  <input id="cm" value="" placeholder="Enter value">
</td>
```